# How to Merge two different values of two different array in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have this kind of table

[image: aa]

I want fetch data like this

[image: a]

i have fetched dishes name(text) but i also need its id with it in a single array how can i do this?
My code is as below:
Controller:-

```
function fetch()
    {
        $this->load->model('fetch');
        $d=$this->fetch->call();
        $e=$d->result();
        $max=$d->num_rows();
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $a[$i]=$e[$i]->product;
            $a2[$i]=$e[$i]->id;
            $b[]=explode(',',$a[$i]);
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($a2);
        $array['arr'] = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map('array_values', $b));
        $this->load->view('display',$array);
    }
```

Model:-

```
function call()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('ruff');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

View:-

```
<body>
<input type="text" name="item" id="txt_search" list="item_list">
<datalist id="item_list">
    <?php
        foreach($arr as $a)
        {
            echo "<option>".$a."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</datalist>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try this...code

```
 $this->load->model('fetch');
    $d=$this->fetch->call();
    $e=$d->result_array();
    // $max=$d->num_rows();
    $products='';
    foreach ($e as $p) {
      $products.=$p['product'];
    }

    $data=explode(',', $products);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually accessing database functions in the controller is not a good practice. So, in order to attend the needs of counting items and such you could change your model to return an array of items.

Model:

```
function call()
{
    $data = array();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ruff');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $data[] = (array)$row;
        }
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, in the `fetch` function in your controller, you can explode the `product` field and create another array to submit to your view.

Controller:

```
function fetch()
{
    $this->load->model('fetch');
    $d=$this->fetch->call();

    $list = array();

    foreach($d as $row)
    {
        $products = explode(',', $row['product']);
        foreach($products as $p)
        {
            $list[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'product' => $p);
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('display',array('arr' => $list));
}
```

It will result you to have an array like the one which follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [product] => veg. burger
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [product] =>  non-veg burger
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [product] =>  chees burger
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [product] => vadapau
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [product] =>  butter vadapau
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [product] =>  chees vadapau
    )
)
```

Now your ids are available in your view.

View:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" name="item" id="txt_search" list="item_list">
    <datalist id="item_list">
    <?php
        foreach($arr as $a)
        {
            echo "<option>".$a['product']."</option>";
            //$a['id']
        }
    ?>
    </datalist>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Your model Code.

```
public function call()
{
   $query = $this->db->select("id,product")
                        ->from("stuff")
                        ->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you will get the result array of data in controller. Here is controller function.

```
public function fetch()
{
    $this->load->model('fetch');

    $result = $this->fetch->call();
    foreach ($result as $value) {
        $newArr = explode(',',$value['product']);   
        foreach ($newArr as  $val) {
            $productArray[]  = array('productID'=>$value['id'],"product"=>$val);
        }
    }
    $data['finalArray'] = $productArray;
    $this->load->view('display',$data);

}
```

Now access the final product array in view. Here is view Code.

```
<input type="text" name="item" id="txt_search" list="item_list">
<table id="item_list" border="1">
    <?php

        foreach($finalArray as $stuffs)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$stuffs['productID']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$stuffs['product']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple code please following code
your model code below:

Model:-

`function call()
    {
       return $this->db->get('ruff')->result_array();
    }`

This code give you all data now controller code like below

Controller:-

`function fetch()
     {
         $this->load->model('fetch');
         $array['arr'] = $this->fetch->call();
         $this->load->view('display',$array);
    }`

This code give you all data now controller code like below

Controller:-

`function fetch()
    {
        $this->load->model('fetch');
        $array['arr'] = $this->fetch->call();
        $this->load->view('display',$array);
    }`
This code give you all data now controller code like below

Controller:-

`function fetch()
    {
        $this->load->model('fetch');
        $array['arr'] = $this->fetch->call();
        $this->load->view('display',$array);
    }`

Now please write code in view 
View:-

`
This code give you all data now controller code like below

Controller:-
`function fetch()
    {
        $this->load->model('fetch');
        $array['arr'] = $this->fetch->call();
        $this->load->view('display',$array);
    }`

Now please write code in view 
View:-

`<body>
    <input type="text" name="item" id="txt_search" list="item_list">
     <datalist id="item_list">
       <?php
          foreach($arr as $value){ 
               $newarray=explode(',',$value);
               foreach($newarray as $test)
                {
                echo "<option value=".$arr['id'].">".$test['product']."</option>";
             }
          }
        ?>
     </datalist>
 </body>`

I think this code will help You
Thanks